# How to get x% of a dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of 3000k rows almost. These are labels of the dataset.

[image]

Now I want to get 10% of each label for early analysis and algorithm. This is a rough estimation.
[image]

Of course, I want shuffled rows in it, meaning that I do not want to do `df[df['Label']==BENIGN].iloc[0:235909,:]` because this will get the first 235k rows, but I want shuffled rows from it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sample`

```
df.groupby('Label').sample(frac=0.1)
```

---

**Edit**: To sample a different fraction for a class:

```
df.groupby('Label').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.01 if x.Label.iloc[0]=='Benign' else 0.1)
```